# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=4.1.0.0 ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: asp.net, iis, .net-4.0, ajaxcontroltoolkit, enterprise-library

Platform : ASP.NET 4.0
Application : A website project with a Datalib ClassLibrary attached to it
Dependencies:
[image: Dependencies of the project]
IIS: 5.1(local and IIS 7.0 online)

I am getting the error at localhost. I haven't checked online yet.
The whole thing was working at ASP.NET 3.5 and now when i upgraded to ASP.NET 4.0 I get the following error.

[image: The yellow screen at Browser]

The Stack Trace is

[image]

At VisualStudio 2010, the error is

[image]

This is not happening everytime.
The first runs always show this error.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's looking in the wrong place for some reason... try adding this assembly to the server GAC and remove it from the BIN folder.

Comment: thanks pal.. i removed the Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary dll and all is working fine.

Comment: i think its cause ajaxcontroltoolkit's entlib.dll strong key is different.